# Call to undefined method Guzzle\Http\Client::request()

Tags: typo3-9.x, omnipay, guzzle, aimeos

I'm using `Aimeos` extension with TYPO3 v9.5.14 to create a Shop website.

I have a problem with the return urls from the payment gateway to the website : `continueurl` / `cancelurl` / `callbackurl` . I get the following error

```
Call to undefined method Guzzle\Http\Client::request()
in /var/www/example.com/typo3conf/ext/aimeos_pay/Resources/Libraries/nobrainerweb/omnipay-quickpay/src/Message/CompleteRequest.php line 44
```

This is the code :

```
public function sendData($data)
{
    $httpResponse =  $this->httpClient->request('get', $this->getEndPoint() . '/payments/' . $this->getTransactionReference(),
        [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode(":" . $this->getApikey()),
            'Accept-Version' => 'v10',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ]
    );
    return $this->response = new Response($this, $httpResponse->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

Guzzle is properly installed through Composer.

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

[image]

Comment: whats is `$this->httpClient` you are just showinf a fragment it lacks a lot of details

Comment: here is the full code : https://github.com/thomasbnielsen/omnipay-quickpay/blob/master/src/Message/CompleteRequest.php

Comment: whats your guzzle version the github repo you showed is using 6.5.x-dev, try to check the dependency version of guzzle for the package you are using

Comment: I installed guzzle using `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^6.5.2` and I updated the composer using `curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php` then `php composer.phar update` but I still have the error `Call to undefined method Guzzle\Http\Client::request()`

Comment: Screenshot : https://ibb.co/5B99FLv

Comment: report it as an issue in the github repo, looks like a bug to me

Comment: I just did that, hoping to get an answer.

Comment: I checked the code, looks like it should be a Psr/Request instance from the interface, share the link of the issue here, for future reference if someone comes with same issue

Comment: I reported the Issue in the github repo : https://github.com/thomasbnielsen/omnipay-quickpay/issues/16